# Incomplete file when extracting from ZipInputStream

Tags: java, http, zip

I have the following method which downloads a zip file and extracts the first entry:

```java
public static Path download(String url) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(url))
            .build();
        HttpResponse<InputStream> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());
        if (response.statusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException(response.toString());
        }
        try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(response.body())) {
            ZipEntry nextEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
            Path file = Path.of(CACHE_PATH, Objects.requireNonNull(nextEntry).getName());
            Files.createDirectories(Path.of(CACHE_PATH));
            Files.copy(zipInputStream, file);
            if (file.toFile().length() != nextEntry.getSize()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("incomplete file: " + file);
            }
            return file;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that sometimes the file is incomplete and no IOException is thrown.
I added the check in order to workaround this issue, but I'm curious what's going on there. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying this code runs to end without exceptions? Make sure `nextEntry.getSize()` is set to value >= 0 before throw ISE.

Comment: *and no IOException is thrown.* What about `IllegalStateException` ? Incidentally, you want `if (!nextEntry.isDirectory() && file.toFile().length() != nextEntry.getSize())`

Comment: How the exceptions `throws IOException, InterruptedException` are handled in the caller method?

Comment: All exceptions are logged, the zip file in question has only one entry, and the end result without the size check is the file is cut in the middle.

Comment: Please give us a url that we can use to test that code

Comment: fwiw I just ran it with a zip archive on my own web server and it worked fine. So you need to post a url that we can use that *you* have a problem with